# How to get java class in CF

Tags: java, cookies, coldfusion, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to access the return value from a java method in my coldfusion file. I have loaded all the jar files in coldfusion file and got the java class object successfully. Using the class object, I want to access java class method which returns a `Set`; but I can't get any return value.
Here is my Java Code:

```java
public Set getSession(String url) {       
    result+="hello";
    try {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
        caps.setCapability(
                PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                "E:\\TicketScraper\\phantomjs\\phantomjs.exe"
        );
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        driver.get(url);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login:loginName")).sendKeys("XXXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login:password")).sendKeys("XXXX");
        waitForJQueryProcessing(driver, 5);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login:j_idt145")).click();        
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        Set<org.openqa.selenium.Cookie> allCookies=driver.manage().getCookies();
        for ( org.openqa.selenium.Cookie loadedCookie : allCookies) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s -> %s", loadedCookie.getName(),loadedCookie.getValue()));
        }      
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return allCookies;
}
```

The java code runs the Phantom JS driver, logs in to the URL in the above code, and gets all cookies. All cookies are collected in a `Set` variable and returned from the method. I want to get this set variable in CF code.

But when I have tried to access the java method's `Set` variable in CF it doesn't return any value. By contrast, when I have commented out all the Phantom JS code and return only a `String` variable then CF can access the string value.
Here is my CF code:

```java
<cfscript>
    paths = arrayNew(1);
    paths[1] = expandPath("lib\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar");
    paths[2] = expandPath("lib\bsh-1.3.0.jar"); 
    paths[3] = expandPath("lib\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar");
    paths[4] = expandPath("lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar");
    paths[5] = expandPath("lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar");
    paths[6] = expandPath("lib\commons-exec-1.1.jar");
    paths[7] = expandPath("lib\commons-io-2.4.jar");
    paths[8] = expandPath("lib\commons-jxpath-1.3.jar");
    paths[9] = expandPath("lib\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar");
    paths[10] = expandPath("lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar");
    paths[11] = expandPath("lib\Counsel_Cookies_Phantom.jar");
    paths[12] = expandPath("lib\cssparser-0.9.14.jar");
    paths[13] = expandPath("lib\gson-2.3.jar");
    paths[14] = expandPath("lib\guava-18.0.jar");
    paths[15] = expandPath("lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar");
    paths[16] = expandPath("lib\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar");
    paths[17] = expandPath("lib\htmlunit-2.15.jar");
    paths[18] = expandPath("lib\htmlunit-core-js-2.15.jar");
    paths[19] = expandPath("lib\httpclient-4.3.4.jar");
    paths[20] = expandPath("lib\httpcore-4.3.2.jar");
    paths[21] = expandPath("lib\httpmime-4.3.4.jar");
    paths[22] = expandPath("lib\ini4j-0.5.2.jar");
    paths[23] = expandPath("lib\jcommander-1.29.jar");
    paths[24] = expandPath("lib\jetty-websocket-8.1.8.jar");
    paths[25] = expandPath("lib\jna-3.4.0.jar");
    paths[26] = expandPath("lib\jna-platform-3.4.0.jar");
    paths[27] = expandPath("lib\junit-dep-4.11.jar");
    paths[28] = expandPath("lib\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar");
    paths[29] = expandPath("lib\nekohtml-1.9.21.jar");
    paths[30] = expandPath("lib\operadriver-1.5.jar");
    paths[31] = expandPath("lib\phantomjsdriver-1.1.0.jar");
    paths[32] = expandPath("lib\protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar");
    paths[33] = expandPath("lib\sac-1.3.jar");
    paths[34] = expandPath("lib\selenium-java-2.44.0.jar");
    paths[35] = expandPath("lib\selenium-java-2.44.0-srcs.jar");
    paths[36] = expandPath("lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar");
    paths[37] = expandPath("lib\testng-6.8.5.jar");
    paths[38] = expandPath("lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar");
    paths[39] = expandPath("lib\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar");
    paths[40] = expandPath("lib\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar");
    paths[41] = expandPath("lib\Selenium_Cookies.jar");
    paths[42] = expandPath("lib\selenium-server-2.0b2.jar");
    //writeDump(paths);

    //create the loader
    loader = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(paths,true);
    //writeDump(loader);

    excelObject = loader.create("counsel_cookies_phantom.Counsel_Cookies_Phantom");
    //writeDump(excelObject);
    //abort;
</cfscript>

<cfdump var=#excelObject.getSession("https://pacer.login.uscourts.gov/csologin/login.jsf")#/>
<cfabort>
```

Please provide your suggestions of how to access the Phantom JS value in CF.

Comment: Your code has a compile time error: `allCookies` at the end is not defined.

Comment: Please edit your question to properly indend your code, fix all the typos (wth is phontom js?), remove the thanks and your name.

Comment: As @ArtjomB said, that code would not compile in java, so either it is not your real code - or you did not verify it actually works in java first. If not, definitely do that first, because if it does not work in java, it certainly won't work from CF either. Also 1) why catch exceptions if the code does nothing with it? and 2) `System.out.println` will not display anything on screen in CF. It will send the output to the CF log files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Set` is a `java.util.Set`, then calling `toArray()` would give you an array that's easily accessible in CF.

e.g.

```
<cfscript>
s = createObject("java", "java.util.HashSet").init();
s.add("foo");
s.add("bar");
s.add("bob");

arr = s.toArray();

writeDump(arr);
</cfscript>
```

[Run this on TryCF.com](http://trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=zRs75XqC)